# Hierarchical data using Custom objects (telerik RadGridView)

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, radgridview

Suppose i have

```
class Person
{
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public List<Person> All {get;set;}

    public Person()
    {
    }

    public List<Person> GetAll()
    {
        //fills the list with person and returns
    }
}
```

and that i have:

```
class Address 
{
    public int PersonId {get;set;}
    public string theAddress {get;set;}
    public List<Address> All {get;set;}

    //constructor, etc

    public List<Address> GetAll()
    {
        //fills the address list and returns
    }
}
```

What im trying to do is exactly the following:

```
//filling the maintemplate with data
radGridView1.DataMember = "Person";
radGridView1.DataSource = new Person().GetAll();     

//address template, the child one
GridViewTemplate template = new GridViewTemplate();
template.DataSource = new Address().GetAll();
template.DataMember = "Address";
radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates.Add(template);

//now the relation between those 2 classes

GridViewRelation relation = new GridViewRelation(radGridView1.MasterTemplate);
relation.ChildTemplate = template;
relation.RelationName = "PersonAddress"; //just a name
relation.ParentColumnNames.Add("Id"); //field to be "joined" to create the relation
relation.ChildColumnNames.Add("PersonId"); //same as above
radGridView1.Relations.Add(relation);
```

and what i get is exactly a gridview with a "+" sign by the side of each Person
The problem is, the "child" grid is EMPTY, and if i try to add data (its, by default, allowed with an empty constructor in the class) i throw an NullArgumentException

Any ideas? im almost giving up. My problem is: i use custom objects on all projects, its not like "yo use datasets, its ready to use etc", i know that, but i would like to know if there's a way to use CUSTOM OBJECTS, or if im done and should try datasets...

Thanks guys

Comment: assuming you have seen the demos for hierarchical grids and also read the documentation for the RadGrid, however there is some straight forward details here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grdunderstandinghierarchy.html

Comment: Well, you pointed me to a link that explains asp.net grid. I'm assuming they're not of the same type, am i right? if i'm wrong i beg your pardon, but im totally new to Paid components. Its usefull but at first time, you get lost (as i am). And Edit: I just tested with a dataset + 2 table adapters pointing to 2 tables, guess what? the same code worked as a charm (but using datasets). Ill read your link again and see if i can get something usefull from that. Many thanks

Comment: after looking at this link http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/CustomDocument5496 i just realized i should migrate to DevExpress, cause they just solved my problem the way i first try to display a master-detail using Telerik's grid. When i downloaded their product, i was expecting a "automatic" recognition of an association inside my list, and that didnt happened. Since im still evaluating their product, im gonna quit and go Dev. Thanks ivanov, for your help and time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using the WinForms implementation. If that's right, then this works for me fine. Please give this a go

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Telerik.WinControls.UI;

namespace RadGridView_Hierarchy_CS
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private List<Person> people = new List<Person>();
        private List<Address> addresses = new List<Address>();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillPeople();
            FillAddresses();

            radGridView1.DataSource = people;

            GridViewTemplate template = new GridViewTemplate();
            template.DataSource = addresses;
            radGridView1.MasterTemplate.Templates.Add(template);

            GridViewRelation relation = new GridViewRelation(radGridView1.MasterTemplate);
            relation.ChildTemplate = template;
            relation.RelationName = "PersonAddress";
            relation.ParentColumnNames.Add("Id");
            relation.ChildColumnNames.Add("PersonId");
            radGridView1.Relations.Add(relation);

        }

        private void FillPeople()
        {
            Person richard = new Person();
            richard.Name = "Richard";
            richard.Id = 1;
            people.Add(richard);
            Person bob = new Person();
            bob.Name = "Bob";
            bob.Id = 2;
            people.Add(richard);
            Person mike = new Person();
            mike.Name = "Mike";
            mike.Id = 3;
            people.Add(mike);
        }

        private void FillAddresses()
        {
            Address house1 = new Address();
            house1.PersonId = 1;
            house1.Id = 1;
            house1.theAddress = "1 The Mews";
            addresses.Add(house1);
            Address house2 = new Address();
            house2.PersonId = 2;
            house2.Id = 2;
            house2.theAddress = "2 The Mews";
            addresses.Add(house2);
        }    
    }

    class Person 
    {     
        public int Id {get;set;}     
        public string Name {get;set;}     


        public Person()     
        { 
        }              
    }

    class Address  
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }   
        public int PersonId {get;set;}    
        public string theAddress {get;set;}     

        public Address()
        { 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer Richard, and i'm gonna accept it as answer since i already chose whose ill buy my components.

Answer (score 2):

stumbled over you post when searching for a solution to this, so ill add my solution in case someone needs it ...  ( using version Q1 2011 ).

in some initialisation method of your UC/Grid you could do something like

```
     //setup the template 
     GridViewTemplate subtemplate = new GridViewTemplate();
     subtemplate.AutoSizeColumnsMode = GridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
     subtemplate.EnableFiltering = false;
     subtemplate.EnableGrouping = false;
     subtemplate.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

     //define / add the cols
     GridViewTextBoxColumn atextcol = new GridViewTextBoxColumn("Name");
     //further properties of atextcol

      //add the cols to the template
      subtemplate.Columns.Add(atextcol);

      //add the template to the grid
      thegrid.Templates.Add(subtemplate);

     //add a HierarchyDataProvider && subscribe to the RowSourceNeeded-Event
      subtemplate.HierarchyDataProvider = new GridViewEventDataProvider(subtemplate);

      thegrid.RowSourceNeeded += new GridViewRowSourceNeededEventHandler(thegrid_RowSourceNeeded);
```

then, in the eventhandler fill the row/rows

```
protected void thegrid_RowSourceNeeded(object sender, GridViewRowSourceNeededEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Template.Rows.Clear();
            patentdata cparent = e.ParentRow.DataBoundItem as patentdata;

            foreach (subdataobject sub in parentdata.subs)
            {
                GridViewRowInfo row = e.Template.Rows.NewRow();
                row.Tag = sub;
                row.Cells["Name"].Value = sub.Name;
                e.SourceCollection.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

so, that would be it. critics ?